# how to place a setTimeout on document.addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Hello  I am new on this forum

in my html code I have a button which has a class which triggers a
document.addEventListener

and I would like my document.addEventListener to be able to trigger 5 seconds after clicking on my button

Is this possible

```
     <a class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart" >
              ajouter au panier
            </a>




<script>
document.addEventListener("click", e => {


  let el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName !== "A") {
    el = el.closest("a");
  }
  if (!el || !el.classList.contains("ajouter-panier")) {
    return;
  }

  const card = el.closest(".testcard");
  if (!card) {
    return;
  }

  const panel = card.querySelector(".panel");
  if (!panel) {
    return;
  }

  e.preventDefault();

  if (el.classList.contains("b-items__item__add-to-cart")) {
    panel.style.display = "block";
  } else if (el.classList.contains("ajouter-panier")) {
    panel.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use `setTimeout`.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: You'd have to split the handler. Some of it has to run directly, for instance it wouldn't make sense to prevent the default behavior of the click event 5s after it occurred. Same may be true for the other logics in there. So you need to determine what needs to run now and what needs to be delayed. Also keep in mind that during the waiting, other events may occur. You might want to handle these differently?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, you just need to encapsulate the logic you want to happen in a setTimeout.

I do not know where you want to do it, but follow the example:

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let btns = Array.prototype.slice.call(btn); 

btns.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Your logic here...
      console.log("works!");
    }, 5000) // 5000ms == 5s | 1000ms == 1s ...
  });
});
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart" name="A">
  ajouter au panier
</a>
```